# Is it possible to mix Direct3D content in a WinRT XAML application?

Tags: windows-8, direct3d, winrt-xaml

My XAML application could use some 3d elements. Is it possible to mix Direct3D content in a WinRT XAML application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's actually very easy to do.  See the [SurfaceImageSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.surfaceimagesource.aspx).  That provides a DirectX surface that can be drawn to like any other surface. See [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) for a lot of detail on this.